# closing brower current tab withour any reference variable mozilla, IE, chrome

Tags: javascript

How can I close browser current tab open by url without a reference (I want to close it on button click)?

Comment: Iam doing single page application app.aspx I load html form by angular routing. in the form I have button to close the aspx page, how do I do

Answer (score 0):

If you don't have a reference to the window, and you don't have the window's *name* (if it has one), you can't close the window. There's no way to look up the window by its URL.

(The name of the window would be the value of the [`target` attribute](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/a) if the window was opened by a link, or the second argument to [`window.open`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/open) if opened that way.)

You used the word "current" in your question, but also said you don't have a reference to the window. If you really meant "current" (the page the button is on), you **do** have a reference to the window: `window`. (Also `self`.) In that case, you may or may not be able to close the window with this code in a click handler on the button calling [`close`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/close):

```
window.close();
```

Comment: Hello T.J.Crowder many thanks , my situation , My  application send Email to customer which has customer rating from as link , if customer given rating, I say thanks for your rating and the button click I want to close the aspx page, can you give any suggestion

Comment: Is the button on the page that they went to when they clicked the link in the email?

Comment: sir, my app send customer feedback email, which contains, feedback.aspx product page link, if customer click the link it open a web page, where customer can give rating, good, badd etc. after customer submit the page, we say popup box thank your for your feedback and one button, close , if customer click the button we need to close the feedback.aspx page

Answer (score 0):

Thank you, now I got answer to close the browser tab for IE, chrome, mozilla

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title></title>   
</head>
<body>

    <input type="button" value="closeWindow1" onclick="windowClose()"  />
   
    <script>
        function windowClose() {
            var win = window.open("about:blank", "_self");
            win.close();
        }
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

thank you all